# How to calculate the interior angles of a convex, equilateral heptagon given some of the interior angles of the heptagon.

Tags: geometry

I cannot find an easy-that of which holds true for any knowledge of mathematics-way to explain, to a peer, the solution, and the reason the solution is true, to the following problem:

*Let H be a convex, equilateral heptagon whose angles measure (in degrees) 168°, 108°, 168°, 108°, x°, y°, and z° in clockwise order. Computer the number y°.*

Will someone please not only show the solution, but put the steps to solve it, and why those steps work, in simple terms so that I may expound it to my peer in a rudimentary fashion?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I clearly stated in the problem everything that is necessary to solve the problem, and I also explained that I can solve the problem, as it is not, to me, a challenging problem, but I require simple steps to reach the solution, and a simple way to explain the, for a peer.

Comment: Then perhaps you ought to ask this question on https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you know the solution you are kindly requested to explain it in your question.

Comment: Thank you, I had hitherto not been aware of that site’s existance. I, however, until I find necssecary upon precedement, will keep question here because I have observed questions such as these on this site.

Comment: I fixed the typo in the title of the question. Thanks for informing me of it.

Comment: I suggest you to construct that heptagon with GeoGebra: that will convince anyone.

Comment: I would start by drawing a picture to convince myself that the problem has a unique solution.  I would also check $x+y+z$ to see if they are very large and we can rely on covexity (we can't).  Then you can take the side to be $1$, locate it in the plane, and compute the coordinates of six of the corners from trig.  You can then compute $y$ from the law of cosines.  I suspect you are expected to find a geometric solution.

Comment: By the way: where did you find that problem?

Comment: I was made aware of the problem when my friend sent it to me because he could not figure it out. I have another friend I am attwmpting to help with maths, so I asked him this, but I am almost sure he won’t have a clue at how to solve it, so I need help putting it simply.

Answer (score 3):

There is no answer.  I constructed it in GeoGebra and the two points are further that $2$ units apart.  You need to reach from $A'$ to $B''$ with two segments of length $1$, but they are over $2$ apart in $y$ alone.
[image]

Comment: Read the problem again, there is an answer.

Comment: @EvanMerrill I checked the answer by hand, the way Ross Millikan indicated in one comment to your question. I used antother coordinate system than them. The distance between the 2 endpoints of the sequence of angles you give in the question is $\approx 2.6$ times the side length, both in my and their calculation. Please check that you got the angles and their order correct!

Comment: The question came from a mathematics competition, and my friend had asked me about the answer because he could not figure it out. The official key had 132 degrees on it, and that's what I got when I did the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's your solution: such heptagon doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: Nope. You're not interpreting the question correctly. I figured out a way to explain it easily, though.. The correct answer was 132 degrees.

Comment: Please write then your own answer, I'm really curious to see it.